# Select box truncating text when body font size changed via javascript on document ready in IE 9

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-9, font-size

IE 9 is behaving quite strangely for me.  I've got a page font-size changing control that saves the users setting and then in the document ready sets the body font-size to that size.  It works fine,   the issue is,  when a page with dropdowns loads, in IE 9,  sometimes the text is cut off.

I've simplified the code down to this jsfiddle to demonstrate.
http://jsfiddle.net/z6Paz/3/

the html:

```
<select id="theSelect" name="theSelect" >                
     <option value="2"  >Letter ( 8.5 x 11&quot; )</option>    
     <option value="3" selected='selected'>A4 ( 8.27 x 11.69&quot; )</option>  
</select>
```

the css:

```
select
{
    font-size:1em;
    width:240px;
}
```

and the javascript:

```
var userPrefSizeOffset = 2;
$(function(){
    var currentFontSize = $('body').css('font-size');
    var currentFontSizeNum = parseFloat(currentFontSize);
    $('body').css('font-size', currentFontSizeNum + userPrefSizeOffset);

});
```

has anyone come across this strange behaviour?  is there a simple fix?

It does not happen in IE 8, or firefox, or safari, or chrome.

Comment: Is your <option> tag set to be a relative size?

Comment: there are no styles affecting the `<option>` tags

Comment: This seems to work fine when I tested it on IE9, can you maybe provide a screenshot of what you're seeing?  Is it possible that you've not specified a doctype on your original, or a non-standard doctype and it's caused your browser to be in quirks mode?

Comment: @PriorityMark  I have a doctype specified, and it doesn't happen on all selects, just some.   The JS Fiddle i liked to shows the behaviour.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Select boxes in IE suffer from a long and unfortunate history of extraordinary bugs.

In the days of IE6, the select box was a windowed OS control—[a wrapper for the Windows Shell ListBox](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/01/17/514076.aspx) that existed in [a separate MSHTML plane](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177378) from most other content.

In IE 7, the control was [rewritten from scratch](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/01/17/514076.aspx) as an intrinsic element rendered directly by the MSHTML engine. This helped with some of the more prominent bugs, but some of this unhappy legacy remains. In particular: after a select box is drawn, changes via the DOM do not always propagate as one might expect.

Here, each option in the select list is drawn to exactly the right width for the text it contains when the control is first rendered. When you increase the text size of the page, IE correctly propagates the change to the control itself but does not adjust the width of the options, so text starts [overflowing to the next line](http://jsfiddle.net/Jordan/PWE44/):

[image: Select box overflowing to the next line in IE9.]

You can fix this by forcing a repaint of the select box. One way to do this is to [append a single space character to the `select` element](http://jsfiddle.net/Jordan/PHsuF/):

```
$('select').append(' ');
```

Alternatively, you could [change the style attribute](http://jsfiddle.net/Jordan/KtaAL/):

```
$('select').attr('style', '');
```

Of these, the `.append()` strategy has the fewest potential side effects and enforces better separation of style and behaviour. (Its essential impact on the DOM is nil.)

Comment: thanks Jordan, This solves it as well.  i JUST gave the bounty to Bharath 2 seconds ago! so i'll give you an upvote.

Comment: No problem, I'm just glad to contribute to this little mystery. :) Thanks for the upvote!

Comment: @Patricia FYI—I couldn't just leave it at "there's a rendering bug," so I've updated my answer with a few more details you might find helpful.

Comment: great extra details!   i think adding the space might be a better option, incase later i want to change my selects to a bigger or smaller relative size. it won't be hard coded in my js!  thanks :)

Comment: Thanks @Patricia! A good mystery isn't the sort of thing I can just leave alone. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Seems IE9 issue. As a workaround, you can refresh the font-size css of select.

```
if(jQuery.browser.msie)
 $("select").css("font-size", "1em")
```

Example.
http://jsfiddle.net/z6Paz/16/

Comment: this totally destroys keeping presentation and logic apart, but it does solve the problem. unlike any of the other answers.   my bounty expires in 5 minutes, so i'll give it to you.

Comment: Thanks :). To safeguard your logics, you can use any kind of unused css to refresh it.

like

if(jQuery.browser.msie)
   $("select").css("direction", "inherit")

Hope this help

Answer (score 2):

Try using the % for scalability. See here for some documentation of `em` vs `%`: http://kyleschaeffer.com/best-practices/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Comment: in this case the best solution IMO is that you should make a JS controller for the font relatively to the screen width/height proportion so that you can verify if the user minimize or changes the size of the browser you could control to see what size the window has so you can change the font size based on that. I can't think of any other alternative.

Comment: it doesn't have anything to do with the browser window size.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that expressing the font size in EMs is the cause. change to pixels and it's fine. This is probably a bug in IE 9.

Comment: it has to be em because it's relative to the body size.  that's the whole point of the font changing control.

Comment: OK - it looks like Microsoft screwed up, so there goes that plan.

Answer (score 1):

This is my first reply to a question, but I found this page because I have had the same problem.

I noticed that just by adding anything to the value in the Dev Toolbar, the text appeared, so what we did was add then remove some white space, which is working perfectly.

Here's the area of our code that did the job:

```
$('select').children().each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).html() +'&nbsp;&nbsp;');
  $(this).html($(this).html());
});
```

I hope that helps someone in the future