# HTML Select cutting text off

Tags: html, css

Ok, as usual, I come here as a last resort after pulling what's left of my hair out and not finding the solution online.

Have a simple table with one row and three cells. Inside two cells are fieldsets (I like the look) containing a `<select>` and two buttons. Everything looks as I want it, except that the text for the options are cut off.

I've tried resizing the select, but can't find any reference on resizing the option itself.

What am I doing wrong?

**The HTML:**

```html
<div id='tabs-1' style='width: 95%;'>
  <table style='width: 98%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;'>
    <tr>
      <td style='width: 33%;text-align: center;'>
        <fieldset style='height: 300px;width: 90%;'>
          <legend>Manual</legend>
          <br>
          <div style='text-align: center;'>
            <a href="#" onclick='getPage("SheriffManual")' target="_self">
              <img src="images/manualIcon.jpg" alt='Manual' height="65">
              <br>
              Sheriff's Policy and Procedure
            </a>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </td>
      <td style='width: 33%;text-align: center;'>
        <fieldset style='height: 300px;width: 90%;'>
          <legend>Memorandum</legend>
          <br>
          <div style='width: 100%;" text-align: center;'>
            <select style='width: 90%;' size="8" id='selSheriffMemorandum' name="selSheriffMemorandum" value="">
              <option value='memorandum/MINIMUM APPLICANT STANDARDS FOR DETENTION, PEACE OFFICERS AND TELECOMMUN.pdf'>Minumum Applicant Standards</option>
              <option value='memorandum/Memorandum EMPLOYEE SMOKING AREAS.pdf'>Employee Smoking Areas</option>
            </select>
            <br><br>
            <div style='float: left; margin-left: 75px;'>
              <button>View</button>
            </div>
            <div style='float: right; margin-right: 75px;'>
              <button>Download</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </td>
      <td style='width: 33%;text-align: center;'>
        <fieldset style='height: 300px;width: 90%;'>
          <legend>Directives</legend>
          <br>
          <select size='8' style='width: 90%' id='selSheriffDirectives' name='selSheriffDirectives' value=''>
            <option value='directives/SHERIFFS DIRECTIVE NO  2015-09-01 WORK PLACE VIOLENCE.pdf'>Workplace Violence</option>
            <option value='directives/Directive ANNUAL TUBERCULOSIS SCREENING.pdf'>Annual Tuberculosis Screening</option>
            <option value='directives/Sheriffs Directive No. 02-03 - Bereavement Leave.pdf'>Bereavement Leave</option>
            <option value='directives/SHERIFFS DIRECTIVE Mental Health Pre-Screening and Diversion NO  2015-01.pdf'>Mental Health Pre-Screening</option>
          </select>
          <br><br>
          <div style='float: left; margin-left: 75px;'>
            <button>View</button>
          </div>
          <div style='float: right; margin-right: 75px;'>
            <button>Download</button>
          </div>
        </fieldset>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**The result:**

[image: Select box cutting off text]

**UPDATE:**  I took out all the CSS and javascript for the page, and the select renders as expected. After putting everything back in, I realized that it was jquery.ui.js causing the problems -- I'm using jquery's tabs and it's setting the `<select>` option width the same as the tab widths. Now I just have to find out what/how I need to override jquery.

Comment: I would firstly recommend getting rid of all your in-line `style` attributes, and put them in a separate css file (or at least a `<style>` tag).  It will be easier to help with this in place.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code, opened it in Firefox and Chrome and it looks fine. No cut-offs. What browser are you using?

Comment: Internet Explorer.  Not by choice, but I works with what they makes me work with.

Comment: looks fine for me in IE11

Comment: wf4 - We're still on 9 until the powers-that-be decree otherwise.

Comment: Get them to degree otherwise quickly. It is beyond EOL and no longer receives security updates.

Comment: I took out all the CSS and javascript for the page, and the select renders as expected.  After putting everything back in, I realized that it was jquery.ui.js causing the problems -- I'm using jquery's tabs and it's setting the <select> option width the same as the tab widths.  Now I just have to find out what/how I need to override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there's a simple fix (courtesy of [Select box truncating text when body font size changed via javascript on document ready in IE 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946510/select-box-truncating-text-when-body-font-size-changed-via-javascript-on-documen)):

```
$('select').append(' ');
```

Forces the select to be redrawn.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a scrollbar to your select elements?

```
<select style='width: 90%; overflow: scroll' size="8" id='selSheriffMemorandum' name="selSheriffMemorandum" value="">
...
</select>
```

Comment: Well, if the <select> tag is big enough, why would I need to put a scroll bar on there?  (not being a jerk, just asking for comprehension's sake)

Comment: Is it possible that your screen size is preventing the box from rendering wide enough?

Comment: I don't think so.  I have plenty of real estate, and the select box itself is sized properly.  It's just the option inside that's cut off.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `height` or `padding` of `<option>`

```
option {
    height:8px;
    padding:8px;
}
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Have you tried using larger padding and higher height?