# Select option text disappears partially after adding css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
 $("select option").each(function() {
   $(this).addClass("heavyError");
  });
  $("select option:selected").attr("selected", false);
});
```

```css
.heavyError {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select style="width:480px; height:100px;" multiple>
<option value="test-ss">test-ss</option>
</select>
<button>test</button>
```

If run this in IE, the text gets cut off by the hyphen, however, it's working properly in Chrome. Not sure what's going on here. Is it a bug with IE or some sort?

Comment: Yes i think it is a problem with IE (select options and multiple)

Comment: I tried something of this sort and landed up in https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11314

Comment: What version of IE?

Comment: @epascarello IE11. Interestingly, I cannot reproduce this issue with IE9.

Comment: on IE11 I can see that bold font value gets converted to 700 in the Computed tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending a `' '` to the `select` will force the select to "refresh", and fixes the issue in IE11. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/9kvcqc05/

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
 $("select option").each(function() {
   $(this).addClass("heavyError");
  });
 
  $("select option:selected").attr("selected", false);
  $("select").append(' ');
});
```

```css
.heavyError {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select style="width:480px; height:100px;" multiple>
<option value="test-ss">test-ss</option>
</select>
<button>test</button>
```

It seems this is just a weird IE-specific bug.

I solved this by referencing [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9065220/2026606) by Jordan Gray.

Answer (score 1):

The best I can figure is that IE is trying to *wrap* the option's text on the hyphen, because the bold style increases its width.

Here's an example with longer text:

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $("select option").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass("heavyError");
  });
});
```

```css
.heavyError {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select style="width:480px; height:100px;" multiple>
  <option value="test-ss">test-loremipsum</option>
</select>
<button>test</button>
```

A quick fix is to append a space to the element:

```js
$("button").on("click", function() {
  $("select option").each(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).text() + ' ');
    $(this).addClass("heavyError");
  });
});
```

```css
.heavyError {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select style="width:480px; height:100px;" multiple>
  <option value="test-ss">test-loremipsum</option>
</select>
<button>test</button>
```